# how to pass a value from form to Ajax.ActionLink as parameter to call a function

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm new to Asp.net and stuck in an issue, here this is my code:
This is my form:

I want to pass SectionName field of form as a parameter to invoke Controller's method.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SectionName)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SectionName, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Section--", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="editor-lable">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)</div>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)</div>
</div>
@*<div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="editor-lable">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AllPresent)</div>
        <div class="checkbox">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.AllPresent)</div>
    </div>*@
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" id="onClick" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>

@foreach (var item in Attendances)
{

    @Ajax.ActionLink(item.SectionName, "AttendanceDetail", "Faculty", new { sectionName = Model.SectionName },
                        new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "p1" })

}

</div>
```

And this is my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AttendanceDetail(GetStudentAttendance_Result model, string sectionName)
{
    GetStudentAttendance_Result at = new GetStudentAttendance_Result() {
        AttendanceDetail = model.AttendanceDetail,
        Name = model.Name,
        RollNo = model.RollNo,
        Present = model.Present,
        StudentId = model.StudentId,
        AttendanceId = model.AttendanceId
    };

    if (sectionName == null) {
        return View(at);
    } else {
        var atten = Db.GetStudentAttendance(sectionName);
        return PartialView("AttendanceDetail", atten);
    }
}
```

Please help me doing this!
Thanks!

Comment: Currently what happens with your code? Any errors/issues?

Comment: Issue is that i want to pass SectionName as parameter to the method when form is submitted, without clicking on the item.SectionName in my view page.

Comment: Whenever i want to take attendance i just want to choose my section from drop down and submit it to controller. but in stated (previous) approach i got section name on my view page and then click on it to pass as parameter for calling the method.